# How to animate when span7 and span5 show hide in bootstrap

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, twitter-bootstrap

I have Bootstrap layout with `span7` and `span5`(inside a span12).I want to hide span7 and expand span5 as span12 when a button click with smooth animation. Same way,onclick of sam button,both span7 and span5 should display.How to achieve this? The inside content also should be flexible as per the parent span.

```
<div id="summary-content" class="contentbar-main" style="display:none;">
                                    <div class="container-fluid">
                                        <div class="row-fluid">
                                            <div class="span12">
                                                <div class="row-fluid no-space">
                                                    <div class="span7" id="sidebarid">
                                                         <div class="myh4">My Summary</div>
                                                         <br>
                                                         <div id="summaryTableId"></div>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="span5" id="contentbarid">
                                                        <div class="row-fluid">
                                                            <div class="span12">
                                                                <div>
                                                                     <span class="summary-left-hide-arrow" id="toggle-button"></span>
                                                                     <span class="myh4">Map</span>
                                                                 </div>
                                                                  <br>
                                                                 <div id="#map-canvas" style="width:100%;height:400px;"></div>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div class="row-fluid">
                                                            <div class="span12">
                                                                <br>
                                                                <div class="myh4">Time Sheet</div><br>
                                                                <div id="newTableId"></div>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming this is the html for a button that does that:

```
<a href="#" id="hideSpan">Hide Span</a>
```

Then the following jQuery should do the trick (put it inside your document.ready function)

```
$('#hideSpan').click(function() {
  $('#sidebarid').removeclass('span7').addClass('hidden');
  $('#contentbarid').removeclass('span5').addClass('span12');
});
```

You will need to add the following css to your page too

```
.hidden { display: none; }
```

UPDATE: Ignore the adding and removing class from the previous example, this should provide a smooth animation.

```
$('#hideSpan').click(function() {
  $('#sidebarid').hide(1000);
  $('#contentbarid').animate({width: '100%'}, 1000);
});
```

Comment: Yes.It works fine. I need smooth animation when sidebar hiding,same time contentbar expand smoothly.I tried like this,But animated randomly.$('#sidebarid').removeClass('span7').addClass('hidden',1000);
    $('#contentbarid').removeClass('span5').addClass('span12',1000);

Comment: Hmm I didn't see the smooth animation bit in the question. It is easy enough to have a smooth animation for hiding something `$('#sidebarid').hide(1000)` but having the expanding as a smooth animation is a bit trickier. I think `$('#contentbarid').animate({width : '100%'}, 1000);` will do it.

Comment: $('#sidebarid').removeClass('span7').addClass('hidden').animate({width : '100%'}, 1000);
      $('#contentbarid').removeClass('span5').addClass('span12').animate({width : '100%'}, 1000);  I tried like this. But not works. I think Hiding one span and expanding one apn at same time is very tricky.